# Linux Compiler for CR16 architecture

Tags: cross-compilation

I have a system that is using a older core, CR16Plus that was made by National Semiconductor, which is now TI.

Unfortunately, TI no longer offers support, or tools, for this processor. I'm trying to find someplace where I can download the tools for Linux.

I've searched online and the only solution I've currently found is to purchase an IDE (which I don't need) from a few vendors like [IAR Systems](https://www.iar.com/iar-embedded-workbench/?focus=wbselector#!?architecture=CR16C&currentTab=features).

Does anyone have a copy or link for the **CR16 Development Toolset** aka **CompactRISC Development Toolset**, or maybe information on old/independent National Semiconductor forums? The actual file was released as:

```
cr16_4.2_linux.tar.gz
```

I'm hoping some forum, hobbyist, etc. has the tools available or knows where to find them, a reach but I'm in a bind, so worth a shot.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get the CR16 toolchain using `binutils/gcc/newlib`:

```
#!/bin/sh
TARGET=cr16-elf
BINUTILS=binutils-2.24
MPFR=mpfr-3.1.5
GMP=gmp-6.1.2
GCC=gcc-6.1.0
MPC=mpc-1.0.3
CLOOG=cloog-0.18.1
ISL=isl-0.16.1
PFXDIR=/opt/cr16
NEWLIB=newlib-2.5.0

NEED_BINUTILS=1
NEED_GCC=1
NEED_NEWLIB=1

CONFIG_OPTS="--disable-multilib --disable-shared --disable-threads --prefix=$PFXDIR --target=$TARGET --with-newlib"
MAKE_OPTS=-j4

# build binutils
rm -rf $BINUTILS binutils-build
if [ $NEED_BINUTILS ] ; then
    tar xfk $BINUTILS.tar.gz
    mkdir -p binutils-build
    cd binutils-build
    ../$BINUTILS/configure $CONFIG_OPTS
    make $MAKE_OPTS 
    make install
    cd ..
fi

# build gcc
rm -rf $MPFR $GMP $MPC $ISL $CLOG $GCC gcc-build
if [ $NEED_GCC ] ; then
    tar xfk $MPFR.tar.xz
    tar xfk $GMP.tar.xz
    tar xfk $MPC.tar.gz
    tar xfk $ISL.tar.bz2
    tar xfk $CLOOG.tar.gz
    tar xfk $GCC.tar.bz2
    mkdir -p gcc-build
    ln -sf ../$MPFR $GCC/mpfr
    ln -sf ../$GMP $GCC/gmp
    ln -sf ../$MPC $GCC/mpc
    ln -sf ../$ISL $GCC/isl
    ln -sf ../$CLOOG $GCC/cloog
    cd gcc-build
    ../$GCC/configure $CONFIG_OPTS --enable-languages=c
    make $MAKE_OPTS all-gcc
    make install-gcc
    make $MAKE_OPTS all-target-libgcc
    make install-target-libgcc
    cd ..
fi

# build newlib
rm -rf $NEWLIB newlib-build
if [ $NEED_NEWLIB ] ; then
    tar xfk $NEWLIB.tar.gz
    mkdir -p newlib-build
    cd newlib-build
    ../$NEWLIB/configure $CONFIG_OPTS
    make $MAKE_OPTS
    make install
    cd ..
fi
```

Comment: I'm going to try this out and accept it if it works, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else runs into a similar issue, I also tried cross-compiling GCC for cr16 architecture using this guide:

http://preshing.com/20141119/how-to-build-a-gcc-cross-compiler/

Unfortunately glibc doesn't support that architecture, so I wasn't able to build GCC either. Looks like for now I have no solution other than purchasing a toolset from a vendor like IAR Systems.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still interested, I've successfully built the CR16C targeted cross-compiler.  Here's a link to my write-up of the process :

https://github.com/clburrus/CR16/blob/master/CR16-dev-build-log.md

As of this writing, I've got a couple copy/paste issues with it, but you'll figure it out.  (You'll see "> sudo make install gmp" which was a carry over from my notes, just make it "> sudo make install".)

It gets you the compiler, the standard library+includes.  I've successfully integrated it into Eclipse-CDT Oxygen, created a project, compiled, assembled and linked.

I'm going to work on doing a vhdl implementation of the CR16B, so I'll be modifying my configuration to ditch the CR16C and CR16C+ instructions.

Enjoy!